# How invert clip selection in JS canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, clip

```
blocksctx.save();
blocksctx.beginPath();
blocksctx.rect((rX-5)*10,(rY-5)*10,110,110);
blocksctx.clip();
```

I want invert this clip region or find another way to draw some rectangle, but not in another rectangle area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for my final code, but I don't know how:

```
blocksctx.save();
blocksctx.beginPath();

blocksctx.rect((rX-29)*10,0,-7000,6000);
blocksctx.rect((rX+30)*10,0,7000,6000);

//why same rects twice times??? otherwise it's not working correctly
blocksctx.rect(0,(rY-29)*10,6000,-7000);blocksctx.rect(0,(rY-29)*10,6000,-7000);
blocksctx.rect(0,(rY+30)*10,6000,7000);blocksctx.rect(0,(rY+30)*10,6000,7000);

blocksctx.clip();
```